# Unable to update kali linux from regular source repositories

Tags: debian, kali-linux

I recently installed Kali Linux 2.0 and tried to update the software.

This is what I did:

I edited `/etc/apt/sources.list`
to contain the following mirrors :

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
```

then ran the following commands:

```
apt-get clean
apt-get update
```

While running the `apt-get update`, I was not able to connect to the Kali server. Here is the error message:

```
Err http://security.kali.org sana/updates InRelease
Err http://http.kali.org sana InRelease
Err http://security.kali.org sana/updates Release.gpg
Unable to connect to kali.mirror.garr.it:http:
Err http://http.kali.org kali-rolling Release.gpg
Unable to connect to kali.mirror.garr.it:http:
Err http://http.kali.org sana Release.gpg
Unable to connect to kali.mirror.garr.it:http:
Segmentation fault Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/Release.gpg
Unable to connect to kali.mirror.garr.it:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/Release.gpg
Unable to connect to kali.mirror.garr.it:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/Release.gpg
Unable to connect to kali.mirror.garr.it:http:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Does that `Segmentation fault` error appear every time you try to update?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You should [NEVER modify](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories) `sources.list` in Kali Linux. Here's what should be in them:

   ```
   deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
   # For source package access, uncomment the following line
   # deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
   ```
2. You probably have no connection to the internet. That's why the `apt-get update` failed.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all different kinds of repositories and been getting all different kinds of errors when i put the command apt-get update.. turned the internet upside down trying to find a solution.... Turns out my organizations firewall has been denying "apt-get" thinking its a download manager.

Comment: Any idea how exactly it detected and blocked it?